# Is there any way to chain optional assignment unwrapping into if conditional in Flutter, the way it is like Swift?

Tags: flutter, unwrap

In Swift, there's a simple language feature to chain unwrapping and checking for non null like this:

```
if let data = functionReturningNullableNumber(), data != 0 { processNum(data) }
if let data = functionReturningNullableString(), data != "" { processStr(data) }
```

In Flutter, currently I have to do this:

```
var dataNum = functionReturningNullableNumber();
if (dataNum != null && dataNum != 0) { processNum(dataNum); }
var dataStr = functionReturningNullableString();
if (dataStr != null && dataStr != "") { processStr(dataStr); }
```

Is it possible to create something similar to the Swift above? Especially the part where I can assign a temporary variable name that will disappear outside of the `if` scope, so I can reuse the variable name.

Of course I can do this:

```
if (functionReturningNullableNumber() != null && functionReturningNullableNumber() != 0) { process(functionReturningNullableNumber()); }
```

But this isn't what I'm searching for.

Comment: Note that for your example you can simply do `functionReturningNullableNumber() != 0`, not sure if the same is possible in flutter (but probably is)

Comment: @Schottky I'm not sure you should. While it compiles, you'd actually have to run the function again inside the brackets to pass the argument to the `processNum` function. In OPs example he assigns the value to a variable `data` so he does not have to call the function again.